# how to run shell script containing sudo command in crontab from mac

Tags: macos, sh

I am able to run shell script with root privillages.but as i need to run it from crontab ,i cant be in root privillages all the time . so how to run this without getting in to root manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cron Jobs are outdated in Mac OS X and you should use LaunchDaemons.

Here is the Guide for LaunchDaemons
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW1-SW1

and refer this for creating Timed Jobs in Mac OS X
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2

LaunchDaemons runs with root user permissions.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the [sudoers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/sudoers.5.html) file to accept running your script without a password

So, you would add something like this:

username ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/script

Note that if this is new to you, I suggest reading about the format of the sudoers file and the commands, rather than just blindly copying the line, so you really understand what is happening here.

Comment: thank you @Merlin069. I am completly new to this.where should i add username ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/script .please let me know

Comment: The sudoers file is located at /etc/sudoers. I strongly suggest reading about it first: http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/intro.html